# macros with multiple arguments in absence of some arguments

Tags: macros, conditionals, optional-arguments

I would like to define a command with two arguments, say `\mycommand{arg1}{arg2}` in such a way that if the second argument is absent, then it takes the first argument in place of the second one, in other words, `\mycommand{arg1}` would be equivalent to `\mycommand{arg1}{arg1}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax **relies** on the fact that one will use braces to enclose  arguments (otherwise the question is ambiguous since *any* subsequent token can be *interpreted* as a second argument).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\mycommand#1{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\mycommandhelp{#1}}{\mycommandhelp{#1}{#1}}}
\makeatother
\def\mycommandhelp#1#2{Mycommands arguments: #1 and #2}
\begin{document}
\mycommand{arg1}

\mycommand{arg1}{arg2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would only add as a proviso that when only one argument is provided, any subsequent space following that argument is gobbled.  If one always wanted to provide a following space, regardless of using 1 or 2 arguments, one could define

```
\def\mycommandhelp#1#2{Mycommands arguments: #1 and #2\ \ignorespaces}
```

If one never wanted to auto-provide the space, then

```
\def\mycommandhelp#1#2{Mycommands arguments: #1 and #2\ignorespaces}
```

could be used.

---

As egreg mentions in his answer, LaTeX provides for optional arguments.  In your case, a simple implementation of that would be:

```
\newcommand\mycommand[2][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1 The arguments are #2 and #2\else
  The arguments are #1 and #2\fi}
```

with the calling syntax as `\mycommand{arg1}` or else `\mycommand[arg1]{arg2}`.

Comment: I confirm that your solution perfectly works.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `xparse` solution using the `g` specifier as a possible optional 2nd (!!!) argument, the `g` specifier allows for `{}` delimited optional arguments, but in my point of view, `[]` would be a clearer way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\xparsecmd}{mg}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    optional #1 and #2
  }{%
    Only #1 and #1
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\xparsecmd{hello}

\xparsecmd{hello}{World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I confirm that your solution perfectly works.

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is realized in the form

```
\foo{Unique}
```

and

```
\foo[One]{Two}
```

which is clearer than an optional argument in braces.

The classical LaTeX way to do this is

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\@dblarg\name@foo}
\def\name@foo[#1]#2{Whatever we want to do with #1 and #2}
```

So calling `\foo{X}` will result in

> Whatever we want to do with X and X

whereas calling `\foo[X]{Y}` will result in

> Whatever we want to do with X and Y

With `xparse` you might do

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\realfoo{#2}{#2}}{\realfoo{#1}{#2}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\realfoo}{mm}{%
  Whatever we want to do with #1 and #2%
}
```

Comment: I confirm that both solutions works. I just have a question why in the first question , there are `[ ]` around `#1` but not around `#2`.

Comment: @Name That's a “delimited argument”: *marginis exiguitas non caperet* would write old man Fermat.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case, here is a Plain solution

- with optional braced 2nd argument:

  ```
  \def\foo#1{\edef\tmp{#1}\futurelet\next\fooaux}
  \def\fooaux{%
    \ifx\next\bgroup
      \expandafter\fooprocess
    \else
      \fooprocess\tmp
    \fi
  }
  \def\fooprocess#1{Something with \tmp\ and #1}

  \foo{bar}

  \foo{bar}{baz}

  \bye
  ```
- with optional bracket 1st argument:

  ```
  \def\foo{\futurelet\next\fooaux}
  \def\fooaux{%
    \ifx\next[
      \expandafter\fooi
    \else
      \expandafter\fooii
    \fi
  }
  \def\fooii#1{\fooi[#1]{#1}}
  \def\fooi[#1]#2{Something with #1 and #2}

  \foo{bar}

  \foo[bar]{baz}

  \bye
  ```

Comment: Why not `\futurelet` also in the first case?

Comment: @egreg -- More flavour ;) Alredy thought about equalizing the two things. Did you implicitely request me to?

Comment: @Ruben I think `\futurelet` is more efficient and doesn't require ending with `=<space>`

Comment: @egreg, you convinced me! updated the first part.